# Separating data functions in Xunit format with Qt -xunitxml

Tags: xml, qt, unit-testing, xunit, qtestlib

I have several unit tests running in Qt 5 some with various data functions, but when I pass the results to Xunit format with -xunitxml flag I lose all the data that I had about the data functions.

Is there a way to keep the data functions as separate tests?

For example I have the testsuite Foo which runs the testcase Bar with two data functions 0 and 1. Just running the tests in Qt gives me this output

```
...
PASS   : Foo::Bar(0)
PASS   : Foo::Bar(1)
...
```

When I apply the -xunitxml flag this is what I get for that test:

```
....
<testcase result="pass" name="initTestCase"/>
<testcase result="pass" name="Bar"/>
<testcase result="pass" name="cleanupTestCase"/>
....
```

And I would like it to show as:

```
...
<testcase result="pass" name="initTestCase"/>
<testcase result="pass" name="Bar(0)"/>
<testcase result="pass" name="Bar(1)"/>
<testcase result="pass" name="cleanupTestCase"/>
...
```